# password_verify no valida contraseñas de más de un carácter

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema para validar las contraseñas que introduzco de dos caracteres o más.

Tengo un campo `varchar(255)` en la base de datos para la contraseña, y la introduzco con:

```
password_hash($_POST['login'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y la compruebo con:

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $password);
```

El caso es que si meto una contraseña **"a"** la verifica sin problemas, pero si la contraseña es **"aa"** ya no la verifica. Esto es muy desconcertante, entendería que no funcionara, pero que funcione sólo con contraseñas de un sólo carácter parece bastante raro.

Esta es la consulta a la base de datos:

```
public function existeUsuario($usuario) {
        self::accesoDB();
        $registro = null;
        try {
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario";
            $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
            $resultado->execute();
            if ($resultado->rowCount() > 0) {
                $registro = $resultado->fetchall();
            }
            return $registro;
        } catch (PDOExceptio $e) {
            echo "Código de error: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
            echo "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine() . "<br />";
            echo "Procedencia " . $e->getTraceAsString() . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Esta es la consulta para crear el usuario:

```
public function nuevoUsuario($usuario, $password) {
        self::accesoDB();
        try {
            if (!self::existeUsuario($usuario)) {
                $consulta = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (usuario, password)"
                        . " VALUES (:usuario, :password)";
                $resultado = self::$conexion->prepare($consulta);
                $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario);
                $resultado->bindParam(":password", $password);
                $resultado->execute();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOExceptio $e) {
            echo "Código de error: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
            echo "Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            echo "Línea: " . $e->getLine() . "<br />";
            echo "Procedencia " . $e->getTraceAsString() . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

El código para crear la contraseña es:

```
$registro = DB::existeUsuario($_POST['login']);
                if (!$registro == null) {
                    $mensaje = "Ese usuario ya existe, por favor introduzca otro.";
                } else {
                    // Encriptamos la contraseña
                    $passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['login'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $resultado = DB::nuevoUsuario($_POST['login'], $passwordHash);
```

Y el código para comprobar la contraseña es:

```
 $registro = DB::existeUsuario($_POST['login']);
 // Si los datos introducidos son correctos, mostramos las opciones de la página
  if ($registro !=null) {
  // Recuperamos de la base de datos los datos del usuario con ese login
      foreach ($registro as $datos) {
         $login = $datos[0];
         $password = $datos[1];
         // Comprobamos que la contraseña introducida sea la misma que la almacenada como hash
         if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            $mensaje = "Contraseña correcta."
         }
```

Comment: A lo mejor no tiene que ver, pero aparentemente estás encriptando el nombre del usuario en vez del pass: `$passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['login'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); $resultado = DB::nuevoUsuario($_POST['login'], $passwordHash);`

Comment: Buen ojo @phpMyGuel. Tampoco entiendo por qué Raúl hace la verificación dentro de un bucle ¿? Se supone que cada usuario entrará de forma individual, ¿no?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias @phpMyGuel! Es un fallo tonto, pero no era capaz de verlo, ahora funciona perfectamente. Y gracias también A. Cedano, ya lo he corregido: $login = $registro[0][0].

Comment: Dado que usas PDO, puedes optimizar el código haciendo un `SELECT` sólo de la columna que te interesa y luego usando `fetchColumn`. No tienes por qué usar `fetchAll` para este caso.

Comment: El caso es que uso la misma consulta para comprobar que exista el usuario y para comprobar que la contraseña sea correcta, por lo que me hacen falta las dos columnas.